# String "START" printed to console during list index

Tags: javascript, list, events, this, innerhtml

I am having trouble indexing a ul list using a forEach loop. The child elements of this list are dynamically created. After adding an event handler to each list item and console logging its innerHTML or textContent upon clicking, I am returned with the string "START" rather than the elements containing HTML or Text.

Secondly, I'd like to be able to have the elements index returned but I run into another issue. When indexing the created array containing each list item's text I am returned with -1 rather than the array element's actual index. Props to anyone who can help me figure this one out! Code bellow:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll("#options-list > li");

itemList = [];
    
items.forEach((item) => {
     itemList.push(item.textContent);
});

items.forEach((item)=>{
    item.addEventListener("click", () => {
        var option = itemList.indexOf(this.textContent);
        console.log(this.innerHTML);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I can use the event object to index the element I am pressing on. Take a look! If their is anyone else who has an alternative solution please post!

```
items.forEach((item)=>{
    item.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        var option = itemList.indexOf(e.target.textContent);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick trick is to use the spread operator to convert the [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) returned by [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) into an Array using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Copy_an_array). *Assuming you want to save it for later use, otherwise just use forEach on the NodeList.*

In the `forEach` you can re-use the item variable inside the listener instead of using `this`. Which does not work because of the arrow function `=>`.
The index is also passed to the [forEach callback](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters).

```js
var items = [...document.querySelectorAll('#options-list > li')]
items.forEach((item, index) => item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log(index, item.innerHTML)
}))
```